# prove continuity of additive function of integer group under topology $T=\{ \mathbb Z,\emptyset \} \cup\{[n,\infty), n \in \mathbb Z\}$

Tags: continuity, topological-groups

Assume that $(\mathbb Z,+)$ be group which has been armed by  topology

$T=\{ \mathbb Z,\emptyset \} \cup\{[n,\infty), n \in \mathbb Z\}$

How to show that additive function($(a,b)\to_f a+b)$ is is continuous under defined topology and inverse function(  $a\to_ga^{-1})$ is not continuous

since pull back of open set $[n,\infty)$   under $g$is not open then  $g$ is no not continuous

I tried to use $\epsilon, \delta $ definition to prove continuity of $f$ 
$$\forall  \quad U_{a+b} : \exists \quad U_a,U_b  \quad\text{s.t}\quad U_a+U_b\subset  U_{a+b} $$
 since all open set in  T has form of $[n,\infty)$ or$[m,n)$ enough to show that 
 above statement for all for every all possible open set  but I think its rough way for this problem.    Does the easy solution??

Comment: $[m,n]$ is not open in this topology.

Answer (score 1):

For $n\in\Bbb Z$ let $U_n=[n,\to)$. Then

$$f^{-1}[U_n]=\{\langle k,\ell\rangle\in\Bbb Z\times\Bbb Z:k+\ell\ge n\}\;,$$

so you need to show that this set is open for any $n\in\Bbb Z$.

HINT: Given $\langle k,\ell\rangle\in f^{-1}[U_n]$, consider the set $U_k\times U_\ell$. Sketching $\Bbb Z\times\Bbb Z$ and $U_n$ might help.